# IOS: CollectionViewCell displaying same content on multiple cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am building an IOS application and I am implementing Pinterest like layout by using collectionviews. I have to calculate image height dynamically which I have achieved already.

My issue is that when I reload the collectionview it does not update the imageview frame it shows the default frame as in the nib file. But the final height of the cell is correct. I am using it like this:

```
[self.photoCollectionView registerClass:[AddImageViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    FRGWaterfallCollectionViewLayout *cvLayout = [[FRGWaterfallCollectionViewLayout alloc] init];
    cvLayout.delegate = self;
    cvLayout.itemWidth = 145.0f;
    cvLayout.topInset = 10.0f;
    cvLayout.bottomInset = 10.0f;
    cvLayout.stickyHeader = NO;
```

And then some dynamic calculations in the cell function. What should I do to make it right?

Images are attached:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialise the frame of your cell using initWithFrame: of the dynamically calculated height.

Comment: and what about the content. It is vanishing sometimes and sometimes the second cell content comes in first one.

Comment: @AleemAhmad That shouldn't be a problem, because everytime you create a new cell, you can set the frame and the content of it. Hope you're initialising the cells of the collection view correctly.

Comment: I am not initializing the cells I am just using this: AddImageViewCell *cell =(AddImageViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];  should this be the problem?

Comment: i think your writing this code in viewDidLoad. if yes then that is problem.

Comment: That shouldn't be the frame. Since you have the cell now, you simply use `[cell setFrame:]` to change the frame size dynamically.

Comment: I am doing it in cellForItemAtIndexPath: function. And cell frame is correct no issues there. The issue is with the inner elements like picture frame and the false content it is displaying.